# How to use transaction with typed dataset in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

Hi
How can I use transaction with typed dataset? Let's say I've a record table and record detail table and I've to save one in the record table and all the details in the record detail table.
How can I use ? I found transaction can be used with untyped dataset but I don't see it with typed dataset. Can someone tell me how I should do?

Kevin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [nice article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/typed_dataset_transaction.aspx) (and code) at CodeProject on how to extend the typed dataset to enable transactions without having them get promoted to a distributed transaction when using the TransactionScope.

Summary: Use the transaction scope with a method added on the partial class to modify the underlying SqlCommand objects to take part in the same transaction.

```
using (SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
{
       // These methods will update all relevant command objects’ transaction property
       adapter1.EnlistTransaction(transaction);
       adapter2.EnlistTransaction(transaction);

       adapter1.Update(table1);
       adapter2.Update(table2);

       transaction.Commit();
}
```

Code example for adapter from reference:

```
public partial class [TableAdapterName]
{
    public void EnlistTransaction(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction transaction)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction _transaction;

        if (this._transaction != null)
        {
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException
        ("This adapter has already been enlisted in a transaction");
        }
        else
        {
            this._transaction = transaction;
            Adapter.UpdateCommand.Transaction = _transaction;
            Adapter.InsertCommand.Transaction = _transaction;
            Adapter.DeleteCommand.Transaction = _transaction;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use TransactionScope and call both the updates within the scope of the TransactionScope object.

Please see the example provided in this link. [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx).

An more close example is provided [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Managing_Transactions_using_TransactionScope.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using transactionscope, since it's difficult for handling code refactor since you can wrap a huge amount of code, this is how I recommend:

This answer it's different because it's adding the transaction for all commands and not only for persistence

Extend your partial Adapter class:

```
partial class YourTableAdapter
{
    public SqlTransaction Transaction
    {
        set
        {
            if (this.CommandCollection != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.CommandCollection.Length; i++)
                {
                    this.CommandCollection[i].Connection = value.Connection;
                    this.CommandCollection[i].Transaction = value;
                }
            }

            this.Connection = value.Connection;
            this._adapter.AplicaTransaction(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Extension method:

```
namespace System
{
    public static class DALSqlExtension
    {
        public static void AplicaTransaction(this SqlDataAdapter _adapter, SqlTransaction transaction)
        {
            if (_adapter == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (_adapter.InsertCommand != null)
            {
                _adapter.InsertCommand.Transaction = transaction;
                _adapter.InsertCommand.Connection = transaction.Connection;
            }
            if (_adapter.UpdateCommand != null)
            {
                _adapter.UpdateCommand.Transaction = transaction;
                _adapter.UpdateCommand.Connection = transaction.Connection;
            }
            if (_adapter.DeleteCommand != null)
            {
                _adapter.DeleteCommand.Transaction = transaction;
                _adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection = transaction.Connection;
            }
            if (_adapter.SelectCommand != null)
            {
                _adapter.SelectCommand.Transaction = transaction;
                _adapter.SelectCommand.Connection = transaction.Connection;
            }
        }
    }
}
```